# How to validate 'required' tag for time type

Tags: validation, go

a `JsonTime` type:

```golang
type JsonTime struct { time.Time }
func (jt JsonTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) { // ... }
func (jt *JsonTime) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error { // ... }
```

a request struct with `required` tag:

```golang
type Req struct {
    StartTime *JsonTime `json:"start_time" schema:"start_time" validate:"required"`
    EndTime   *JsonTime `json:"end_time" schema:"end_time" validate:"required"`
}
```

main:

```golang
var req Req
vErr := Valid.Struct(req)
```

err:

```
err(schema: error converting value for "start_time". Details: parsing time "2020-01-01 00:00:00" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse " 00:00:00" as "T" (and 1 other error),<nil>)
```

How to use my standard time format instead of UTC time format for 'required' validation?

Comment: I believe this has nothing to do with `required`, it instead depends on how you've implemented `UnmarshalJSON`, can you share that piece of code, also can you share an example of the input you're trying to handle?

Comment: could you show which library of validator you use?